# How to setup magenta music framework in Vue or Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-cli-3, tensorflow.js, magenta

I want to understand the proper way to setup magenta music framework in Vue or Nuxt template. So far, I am unable to find an example. Can somebody help me with this setup?

I am following the hello world example for magenta music from (https://hello-magenta.glitch.me/) and trying to incorporate this example in VueJS or NuxtJS framework

Here is the link to the repo where i tried to setup Magenta with VueJS- https://github.com/Dantonyswamy/magentamusic-vue

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Can you show us where you are stuck?

Comment: Hi @ThomasDondorf, Here is the repo link for the file setup. I am not sure where I am going wrong - https://github.com/Dantonyswamy/magentamusic-vue

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the module at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@magenta/music

```sh
npm i @magenta/music
```

2. Register the module with the main.js in vue or nuxt.

```
const model = require('@magenta/music/node/music_vae');
const core = require('@magenta/music/node/core');

// These hacks below are needed because the library uses performance and fetch which
// exist in browsers but not in node. We are working on simplifying this!
const globalAny: any = global;
globalAny.performance = Date;
globalAny.fetch = require('node-fetch');

// Your code:
const model = new mode.MusicVAE('/path/to/checkpoint');
const player = new core.Player();
model
  .initialize()
  .then(() => model.sample(1))
  .then(samples => {
    player.resumeContext();
    player.start(samples[0])
  });
```

Comment: I tried out the npm install module and I am not hearing the music at all. Here is the repo link where I've tried to setup magenta music on VueJS template - https://github.com/Dantonyswamy/magentamusic-vue. Can you tell me where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Actually got this working on the Vue template. I created a separate JS file and made sure the "model" variable and the newly instantiated class variable "mm" to be different and it was working fine.

Here is the separate JS file:
  ./plugins/magenta.js

```
    const mm = require("@magenta/music/node/music_vae");
    const core = require("@magenta/music/node/core");

    const globalAny = global;
    globalAny.performance = Date;
    globalAny.fetch = require("node-fetch");

    const model = new mm.MusicVAE(
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/magentadata/js/checkpoints/music_vae/mel_2bar_small"
    );
    const player = new core.Player();

export { player };
export { model };
```

Exported the player and model to the vue component 
/components/music.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-col cols="12">
      <v-row align="center" justify="center">
        <v-card class="mx-auto" max-width="400">
          <v-card-text>
            <div>Web experiment with</div>
            <p class="display-1 text--primary">
              Ma•gen•ta
            </p>
            <p>
              trying to make it happen on VueJS template. Hopefully it works!
            </p>
            <div class="text--primary">
              click the play button to hear .<br />
              "Twinkle Twinkle little star" music
            </div>
          </v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-btn text color="deep-purple accent-4" @click="play">
              Play
            </v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-row>
    </v-col>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>
import { player, model } from "@/plugins/magenta";
export default {

  methods: {
    play() {
      model
        .initialize()
        .then(() => model.sample(1))
        .then(samples => {
          player.resumeContext();
          player.start(samples[0]);
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```